# RelativeLayout hides prior LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have an XML representing single line in some app, containing name, grade, and picture.

Name + Grade are vertically set in the line, to the left, and my intention is to get the picture to be on the right side of the line.

I'm trying to use `RelativeLayout`, in order to align an `ImageView` to the right side of screen, as I understood this is the correct way to do this, but it hides my other layouts -

Only the image view is visible when using it.

Tried changing the layout width\height to match parent but that didn't help.

What is it i'm misunderstading? What is my incorrect usage here?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_line"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FF00">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="start|center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tv_example"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:focusable="false">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_grade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="@string/tv_example"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:focusable="false">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout make everything become easier

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_pic"
        android:gravity="start|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="tv_exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_grade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="tv_example"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ff0000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this it what you want

[image]

Comment: That helps, only problem with that usage is that very long text in the `TextView` makes some of the text be hidden behind the picture, instead of ending with `...` before the `ImageView`

Comment: I edited my answer. Use singleLine="true" instead of maxLines="1".

Comment: Still doesn't do the trick.. I get a line of `<text _start        <image> text_end ...>`

Comment: Do you see my preview? Just copy the whole piece of code and replace with yours.

Comment: Haven't been home yet :) Will check this evening! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set weight sum to first/root `LinearLayout`? If no add `android:weightSum="3"` to root LL. after that add `layout_weight="2"` to your RelativeLayout

Comment: Tried now, `TextView`s are showing only 1 char,even though there is a lot of free space in the line to show entire text, while `ImageView` aligned to the right

Comment: You can change layout_weight value of Linear and Relative layouts to get perfect result just experiment it. I think it will be better if you will change layout_weight= of LinearLayout to 3 and relativeLayout's to 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Put your child `LinearLayout` like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="start|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

And your child `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

I recommend you using `RelativeLayout` for all your XML or maybe you can take a look to the `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by replacing your parent `LinearLayout` with `FrameLayout`.

But for showing ... at the end of the text, you have to give a fixed width to the `TextView` using weight or static width in your existing layout.